# How enable looping on a Ringtone instance for API lower than 28?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following method

```
    private void playRingtone() {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse(Constants.ANDROID_RESOURCE_ROOT + this.getPackageName() +
                Constants.SLASH_SEPARATOR + R.raw.sound);
        this.ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.getApplicationContext(), sound);
        this.ringtone.setLooping(Boolean.TRUE);
        this.ringtone.play();
    }
```

On line `setLooping(Boolean.TRUE);`, the following message is appeared

> Call requires API level 28 (current min is 21): android.media.Ringtone#setLooping

Has the `Ringtone` instance any other method that replaces `setLooping` on APIs lower than 28?

Comment: I looked [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/Ringtone), it seemed impossible.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're creating specifically a `Ringtone` object for that? Couldn't you just use a `MediaPlayer` instead? E.g., `MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);`, `player.setLooping(true);`, `player.start();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a `timerTask` inside a `scheduleAtFixedRate` to check if it is still playing

It goes something like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (!this.ringtone.isPlaying()) {
            this.ringtone.play();
        }
    }
}, 1000, 100);
```

Where the `1000` is the time when the timer starts to run and `100` is the time for interval

Hope this help

Comment: So, `Timer` plays as a **`Thread`**, doesn't it?
But, in this case, this `TimerTask` runs indefinitely? Or can I set a limit?

Comment: you can add a limit by adding a incrementing value inside it or just add a listener or something to stop the thread

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have a `setLooping` method replacement. There is only a `play()` method, and that is what you will be forced to work with.

Works Cited https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/Ringtone